# How to open ports on EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, port, ubuntu-18.04

I'm setting up a new server in AWS, Ubuntu 18.04 and created the inbound rules and attached to the server permitting the port:

Custom TCP Rule TCP 7096 0.0.0.0/0

Custom TCP Rule TCP 7096 ::/0

and have a script php file that has to be acessed in that port, and I used UFW created the rules permitting the port: 7096 and finally I disabled it, I'm using a site that checks if the port is open and no matter what I do, the access is always not permitted. I have tryed many solutions found on the net but nothing solves. All other rules are ok for ports: 80, 22, 3306, but for that no way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your security group is configured properly, which it seems like it probably is based on the inbound rules you've defined, it could be that your EC2 instance isn't reachable from the internet.

Is the instance in a public subnet? Does it have a public IP assigned? Are you testing connectivity using the IP or the AWS domain name? Is it in the default VPC? Or have you made your own?

There's a myriad of reasons why it might be failing, so it will be difficult to figure out without some more information.

Comment: I installed nmap and the result was that: 
Scanning localhost (127.0.0.1) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 3306/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 127.0.0.1
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 02:31, 1.56s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000040s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql, now where I open this?

Comment: Do you have anything listening on port 7096? Just having the port available in the security group doesn't necessarily mean the port will be available if there's nothing bound to it.

Comment: Yes inbound rules, I'm using a elastic ip and have an application running ok, now I understanding that I have to open the port in the operating system, I thought that opening the port using UFW was enough...

Comment: I'm confused in UFW shows that the port is open, but in nmap it's closed.